# What is the difference between home$ and ~$?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, directory, directory-structure

In the below screenshot, I was not able to understand the **third** shortcut of *Table 2-1*.

It says that `cd ~user_name` will change the working directory to the home directory of the *user_name*. But, when I entered this command, I was in the same directory i.e, **~$** and not in **/home$**. Why?

Are they both same ?

I think the formal one is the user directory and the later one is the home directory.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

Whatever you're saying about **~$**, **home$**, and **/home$**
doesn't make much sense. 
I guess you're talking about your command line prompt;
if so, it would have been useful to show what you typed and what happened
(and then explained what you expected).

But I can read minds, so I believe that I understand the issue:
**~** and **~user239887** (assuming `user239887` is *your* real user name)
mean the same thing.  If you were to type

```
cd ~gman
```

that would take you to *my* home directory,
and your shell prompt would probably look something like **`/home/gman$`**.

---

In the beginning, the shell prompt was always two characters —
a printing character and a space. 
If you were a system administrator, your prompt was "`#` ";
otherwise, it was "`$` " or "`%` ". 
And then God said, "Let there be fancy shell prompts,"
and, lo, there were fancy shell prompts. 
Shell prompts started showing the user's name, the system name,
the time, and the phase of the moon (do you think I'm kidding?),
all in color.

One of the most popular customizations to the shell prompt
is to include the current directory. 
Your shell prompt is probably your current directory followed by "**`$`** ".

Another **cool thing**™ was that you were able
to specify your own home directory by typing "**`~`**". 
Because of this, when your current directory is your home directory
and your shell prompt is configured to display your current directory,
then the shell prompt displays "**`~`**". 
But anyplace else, it shows the actual pathname
(except it might show "**`~gman`**" when you are in *my* home directory,
`/home/gman`).

*Your* home directory is probably `/home/user239887`. 
As I said earlier, you can refer to it as **~** or **~user239887**. 
When you login, you are in your home directory,
so your prompt is "**`~$`** ". 
If you type **`cd ..`**, then you go to the `/home` directory,
which is the *parent* directory of your home directory,
and your prompt becomes "**`/home$`** ".

At the risk of repeating myself, ***NO***,
`/home` is not your home directory. 
Your home directory is probably `/home/user239887`. 
`/home` is the *parent* directory of your home directory.

Comment: my question is are /home$ and /home/user_name are same ?

Comment: ~ and ~user239887 mean the same thing when you are logged in as user239887.

Comment: if /home/user_name is called home directory of user_name than what  /home is called ?

Comment: @user239887 The string ` /home$` is not part of a normal command. $HOME is a variable set to your homedir. Your homedir is defined in /etc/passwd and might be `/home/user239887`.

Comment: @user239887: Please explain ***what you are talking about*** when you say **`/home$`**.

Comment: on entering command **cd ../** the prompt change from ~$ to /home$ that is why i have asked if /home is home directory than why /home/user_name is called home directory

Comment: @user239887 I think you misunderstood one thing : `/home` is **NOT** the home directory. It is the directory that contains all home directories. Your home directory is `~`, which is the same as saying `/home/your_username`, but in no case is `/home` the home directory of anybody.

Comment: ok thanks! /home doesn't mean home directory .it is parent directory of home directory right?

Comment: @user239887 right.

Answer (score 3):

The `$HOME` environment variable is commonly set and exported by `login` to the pathname of a user's home directory when a user logs in. A POSIX-compatible shell will use the value of this environment variable in a context when it should perform a `~` *tilde* expansion to complete a path to a username's home directory but the actual expanded field is otherwise null. Aside from its association with the shell's *tilde* expansion and with `/bin/login` the `$HOME` shell variable is in no other case exceptional - it is handled by the shell as any other shell variable might be. The shell's *tilde* expansion, however, is unique as shell expansions go in almost every way.

This is a little a difficult to grasp at first - and is probably why the *tilde* expansion is so underused despite its immunity to the many varied kinds of shell-expansion vulnerabilities that can often negatively affect the more common kinds.

The shell might portably consider a *tilde* eligible for expansion if read in any of the following contexts:

1. Immediately follows either the first `=` or any colon-character in a shell-variable assignment.
2. Begins any shell argument word.
3. Begins a shell path and either completes at least one full properly delimited path component all alone or can verifiably do so with trailing context.

Even in these cases the `~` *tilde* will *not* be expanded if it is quoted, or if the context somehow precludes its expanding *wholly* to some user's home directory or the current value of the `$HOME` environment variable. In other words, the shell *will not* perform any *tilde* expansions if the context of the expansion is at all uncertain. While the shell will happily expand `$var_not_var` away to null, it will refuse every time to make similar guesses about a `~`.

The `$HOME` substitution, for example, can only occur if the *tilde*'s possible expansion field is null - which is to say that its position in the argument list unequivocally guarantees its eligibility for expansion because it is delimited on all sides.

The only other case that a *tilde* might be expanded is when its trailing context completely matches a verified system username - in which case it is substituted for a path to said user's assigned home directory as reported-on by the system. The shell should compare the context against a list of the system's registered users and *only* expand if the trailing context matches one of them.

To clarify what I mean by a *null* or *not-null* `~` expansion field, here are a few examples:

```
printf %s\\n ~some_user_name ~some_user_name/some_more_stuff
```

Both of the above expansion contexts are *not* null - the tilde can only expand to the pathname of *some_user_name*'s home directory and only if there is such a registered username on the current system. The second `~` should expand *(or not expand)* identically to the first because the path `/` separator character delimits the trailing context. If the shell cannot verify the existence of *some_user_name* then the `~` should remain *just a tilde*.

```
printf %s\\n ~/some_user_name /~/ ~
```

But here the expansion fields for the first and third *tildes are* null. The first is delimited by the path separator char. The second is similarly delimited, but is not even considered for expansion because it does not lead the shell word. The first and third *tildes* should both expand to the current value of the `$HOME` environment variable, and the results of the expansion should be equivalent to:

```
printf %s\\n "$HOME"/some_user_name /~/ "$HOME"
```

Note that the `"$HOME"/some_user_name` path above need not actually exist to qualify the tilde for expansion - as is also true of the previous `~some_user_name/some_more_stuff` example - which is a unique attribute among portable path expansions. Typical *filename generation* or *shell globbing* behavior as might be attempted with the special shell chars `?[*` is only to expand these characters away if they *match* a resolved pathname but otherwise to let them remain literally. The *tilde*, however, instead adopts an *arbitrary preassigned value*  - as specified in `$HOME` - when a match cannot be had so long as its expansion eligibility is absolute.

Note also that the quotes used above are intentional - while the `~` *tilde* expansion will not occur in quotes, the value of its expansion is always literal and never subject to further pathname expansions or shell splitting of any kind. It expands in the same way most other expansions require quotes to do - when it expands at all. This is *(possibly very usefully)* contrasted, of course, by the expansion behavior of the actual `$HOME` environment variable.

As I previously hinted, the `~` *tilde* expansion can only occur in either an argument or assignment context unless the expansion completes a delimited path component of an executable command. And so a `~` passed alone in command position will not be subject to expansion. It is therefore possible to assign a `~` shell `alias` such that the command:

```
~ ~
```

...results in two independently and uniquely expanded values which are processed entirely based on input context. A user might even define the `~` `alias` to define the value of the `$HOME` shell variable when called such that the second *tilde*'s expansion is altered by the first *(and possibly even vice-versa with recursion)*.

In fact, I like to think of the `~` *tilde* as a kind of *argument alias*. I often use it in combination with `$IFS` - to the effects of which its expansions are immune - and `$*` and `eval`. I consider that it lends itself remarkably well to `$IFS` contexts because - as a single character - it can either be removed from a string entirely with a single expansion, or else safely substitute in any number of other characters per occurrence as I desire it. An argument array that looks like:

```
"$argv1" ~ "$argv2" ~ "$argv3" ~
```

...might be *(safely)* any number of things at any given time by merely temporarily reassigning the value of `$HOME` to whatever I wish and re`eval`uating it. Such an argument array can even be generated from any other on the original argument delimiter points with a little dextrous application of `$*` substitutions.

Another construct I like to use is:

```
for HOME in ./* ~; do stuff w/ $HOME and ~; done
```

...which gets me *two* values for each iteration's assignment. To one of these I can freely apply parsing in the form of `$IFS` splitting or additional glob characters immediately alongisde the other which will always literally refer to the iteration's original argument value. And what's more, I can do these things side-by-side in the same command's argument list and without overly cluttering it with shell-quotes.

It is this last point, I think, which most clearly demonstrates the difference between `$HOME` and `~`.

Answer (score 2):

In shell, user's home directory is located in `/home/username`,

`~` is shortcut for home directory of the **current** user using the shell,

`~usr` is shortcut for home directory of user with username `usr`,
so `~usr` is the same as `/home/usr`. If your username is `usr`, then `~` and `~usr` are the same.

The home directory of current user is also saved in variable `$HOME`.